# color de tema línea de código

Tags: visual-studio

quizá mi pregunta es tonta, pero saben cómo cambiar el color de la línea de código o remarcado.el tema se llama nocterial palenight ya intenté entrar a las configuraciones del tema pero no se puede modificar. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nada mejor que preguntarle a quien escribio el tema, no?